# old_id to new_id (parent-child) relationship

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to fetch a last new_id for the first old_id, for that I have input data as following in the table named as **temp_table**:

```
OLD_ID    NEW_ID    CHANGE_DATE
A         B         2024-01-25
B         C         2024-01-26
C         D         2024-01-27
W         X         2024-01-28
X         Y         2024-01-29
Y         Z         2024-01-30
```

I have tried a below query in snowflake:

```
select
old_id, connect_by_root new_id as new_id
from temp_table
connect by
  prior old_id= new_id
  order by old_id;
```

For that I am getting results as below:

```
OLD_ID  NEW_ID
A       B
A       C
A       D
B       C
B       D
C       D
W       X
W       Y
W       Z
X       Y
X       Z
Y       Z
```

but the expected output I want is just two lines as below:

```
    old_id        new_id
    A             D
    W             Z
```

I have tried to use window functions but its not allowing to use it in recursive CTE's.

Another approach is using sys_connect_by_path but still problem remains same to print only desired output.

```
select sys_connect_by_path(old_id, '->'), new_id, level
from temp table
connect by 
    old_id = prior new_id
    order by old_id;
```

Comment: Which RDBMS you are using ? Please tag only the one you are using

Answer (score 0):

As long as the ids are unique to one path, some filtering after your recursive query would work:

```sql
with data as (
    select split(value, '         ') x, x[0] OLD_ID, x[1] NEW_ID, x[2] CHANGE_DATE
    from table(split_to_table('A         B         2024-01-25
B         C         2024-01-26
C         D         2024-01-27
W         X         2024-01-28
X         Y         2024-01-29
Y         Z         2024-01-30', '\n'))
),
recursive_data as (
    select old_id, connect_by_root new_id as new_id, SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(new_id, '<') ||'<'||old_id path
    from data
    connect by
      prior old_id= new_id
      order by old_id
)

select *
from recursive_data
where old_id not in (select new_id from data)
and new_id not in (select old_id from data)
;
```

[image]